# 'Reading, ..., is not language, but technology.'

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [[Source:]](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3937/5306) Reading, on the other hand, is not language, but **technology**. There is no human adaptation to literacy as there is to spoken (i.e, real) language, and in fact some humans never manage to master literacy in their native language, while others find it very simple.

Which [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/technology) of technology fits here? I don't understand its use; is it figurative?

PS: p 295, *Linguistics For Dummies* (1 ed, 2012; by Déchaine, Burton, Vatikiotis-Bateson) aided to resolve my confusion:

> Writing is a technology: It has a design and a purpose. The design: using
>   symbols to represent spoken language. The purpose: keeping records and
>   communicating over long-distances. But the world wasn’t always this way. [...] Surprisingly, humans had
>   these skills for all of 40 millennia — making symbolic pictures and using
>   language — without ever thinking of *using* their symbolic pictures to represent
>   specifically the sounds or words in any language.

Comment: I think they mean it as literal... Technology in the same sense that a computer is technology now.

Comment: Greek  *techne*.  Something *devised* by humans.

Comment: Implicit in "reading" is "writing" -- a system of recording some (not all) features of language-acts or speech-acts (or "speech") on a physical medium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typical pronouncement from our [highly esteemed] retired linguistics professor [John Lawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/482/jlawler). If I'm worthy to set forth his position, it's that he considers "real" language to be a ***spoken*** form of communication, in which context *writing* is just a crude attempt to reproduce language in a visual (*tactile*, for [Braille](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Braille)) form.

For most of us, *speaking* requires no "technology" whatsoever - all you need is the standard biological attributes (lips, tongue, larynx, lungs, etc.). But almost *any* form of writing requires "manufactured" equipment (writing implements, paper, keyboards, etc.).

For what it's worth, I completely agree with John, and have little interest in punctuation, spelling, and other aspects of typography. In principle, you can be perfectly fluent in a language even if you can't read or write a word of it. I know a senior English teacher who's been blind for decades, but never learned Braille, and his competence in English is unquestionable.

---

EDIT: I've just realised that Prof Lawler was specifically addressing *reading* (a corollary to *writing*, but a significantly different process). Even more specifically, he was explaining that since "real" language is a *fundamentally oral/aural faculty, "naturally" accessible to everyone though speech/hearing*...

> */ɪf ɪŋɡlɪʃ wərɪtən fəniməkli, ɪtəd be iziər tərid/*
>
> If English were written phonemically, it'd be easier to read ("...it **would** be easier...")

Possibly for *him*, that phonetic representation really might be "easier" even now, but I doubt it. Personally I found it quite taxing, even though I could pretty much guess what he'd be saying before I tried to "decode" it. But his point was that *in absolute terms*, if all writing were phonetic, teaching basic literacy skills to schoolchildren would be far simpler than it is now.

In that precise context, Prof Lawler said *converting language to written symbols is technology*, by which he means *a manufactured, designed product*. But whereas we can [*replace incandescent bulbs with leds*](http://eartheasy.com/live_led_bulbs_comparison.html) for a "better-designed" product, we can't easily change written language. We can actually change ("improve"?! :) the *spoken* form more easily than the written, which is why much of our confusing [orthography](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthography) depends on "historical" factors, not current *language*.

Comment: Your IPA says “fəniməkli”, but your text says “phonetically”. Shouldn't it be “phonemically”?

Comment: @Arturo: Oops! Well, I did say I found it taxing! Anyway, thanx - I'll edit.

Comment: Easy is what you have learned by heart.  The symbols we use could represent ideas, words, sound clusters/syllables, or individual phonemes.

Comment: @TRomano: Perhaps you didn't pick up on John's point (maybe I didn't explain very well). What he meant was we "naturally" recognise and know how interpret *spoken language*, so learning to read really would be ***objectively*** easier if writing were consistently phonemic. Realistically, no-one would say the process by which children acquire (spoken) language involves "learning by heart". Okay - they *would* have to learn a few dozen symbols (IPA, or whatever) to master "phonemic orthography", but that really would be trivial compared to the system we have now.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I understand his point quite well. But consider the phonemic orthography of the early middle ages in England, when there were more than two dozen ways to spell the word for "sister". Just whose pronunciation would be the standard for the phonemic spelling? And if there were more than one way to spell a word (indeed, many ways) that would have serious problems of its own. The programmers at Google would go crazy.

Comment: @TRomano: Nevertheless, I would say the relationship between phonemic transcription and "inate" language (speech) is an order of magnitude closer than current written English. You might as well fret over how to transcribe *volume*, for example. Details, really.

Comment: Pronunciation changes over time, and so, with time, the "accurate" phonemic relationship would become muddy. Adept readers come to recognize words even when the letters are all munged. *You cn prbbly rd this evn thgh mny of the vwls hv bn rmvd*.  It's only the beginner who sounds words out syllable by syllable.

Comment: @TRomano: Okay, I'm convinced. My "order of magnitude" was *way* OTT - in *most* regional/sociolingistic sectors, phonemic transcription would be a *bit* easier to learn/teach *for a generation or two,* But it's all just arbitrary symbol sets in the final analysis, and eventually the link between current oral communication and historical recordings would get weaker and weaker, so "mapping" the symbols would get harder. I remember as a schoolboy listening to *The Canterbury Tales* read as we suppose it sounded at the time (I barely understood a single word! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: "Arbitrary symbol sets". Yes. That's what I was trying to get at above: *The symbols we use [when devising a writing system] could represent ideas, words, sound clusters/syllables, or individual phonemes*.

Answer (score 2):

The writer is trying to say that written language is not a natural human ability but an invention, that is, that it's more like a hammer than it is like a fist.

One could debate exactly what that means and whether it's true.

Comment: OK. Of course it's true.